# In Ubuntu, when a window is set to half screen, select other half like Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screen, resize

In Windows 10, when you set a window to half of the screen, the rest of opened windows are shown at the same time in the other half so you can easily choose the one you want to fill the other half of the screen with.
https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-split-screen-on-windows

Can Ubuntu 22.04 do this or similar?

Answer (score 1):

If its not already installed, install `Extension Manager` in v22.04

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Then select the app and then `Browse` and in the search box enter "tile windows" which will present you with a number of extensions for you try at will. Realistically, only select those that are marked "Install" as others marked "unsupported" will more than likely not (yet anyway) be suited to the GNOME 42 environment used by v22.04 LTS.

[image]